# How can I debug a udev rule?

Tags: usb, udev, qemu

I want to make a USB audio device accessible for passthrough to QEMU. I have created a udev rule but it is not working. I would like to know how I can debug this issue?

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0d8c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8808", MODE="0666"
```

Comment: I have already figured this out, I'm documenting my answer now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I eventually isolated the problem. Udev checks the rule specification against a hierarchy of device attributes ranging from the USB host controller down to the device itself. These different nodes have a collection of attributes that can be specified in the udev rule.

To see observe the execution of rules, use the following command:

```
udevadm control --log-priority=debug
journalctl -f
```

If you don't see your rule in the logs even after reloading udev and reseating the device, ensure that the file name format is consistent with udev expectations: 99-name.rules

To see observe udev events, use the following command:

```
udevadm monitor --environment
```

To see the attributes for a specific device, use the following command:

```
udevadm info -q all -a /path/to/device/as/seen/in/aformentioned/logs
```

You'll see a series of attributes blocks, such as the following

```
  looking at device '/devices/...':
    KERNEL=="event3"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/...':
    KERNELS=="input23"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{name}=="Speed Dragon USB Advanced Audio Device"
    ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input3"
    ATTRS{properties}=="0"
    ATTRS{uniq}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/...':
    KERNELS=="1-5"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="16"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="11"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="5"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="8808"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0d8c"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Speed Dragon"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB Advanced Audio Device"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="7861"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
```

Matching my device to the last block, I eventually realized that my udev rule should have specified `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"` instead of `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"`. Which is a sad discovery to make :(

Once the correct rule was specified:

**Note that invalid or incorrect attributes are silently ignored**.

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0d8c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8808", MODE="0666"
```

And Udev was reloaded via:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

And the device was unplugged / plugged, the correct permissions were registered.

Comment: Real udev rule debugging is a PITA, but you can also restart `udevd` in verbose mode, which helps a bit of staring at attributes doesn't help.

Comment: Good point. Running this command also helps: udevadm monitor --environment